# select distinct columns based on lastest record

Tags: mysql, sql

I mentioned the table structure below I want to select distinct value where the lastest record of column Fresh_Call = yes.

I am trying this SQL but I am not getting actual output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customerId, Fresh_Call, Call_Status FROM interation_logs WHERE Call_Status='notconnected' AND Fresh_Call='yes'

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `interation_logs` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customerId` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `process_userid` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Call_Status` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Reason` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Conversation` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Fresh_Call` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Action` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Dnt` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `interation_logs`
--

INSERT INTO `interation_logs` (`Id`, `customerId`, `process_userid`, `Call_Status`, `Reason`, `Conversation`, `Fresh_Call`, `Action`, `Dnt`) VALUES
(1, '1', '2', 'notconnected', 'switchoff', 'No Conversation', 'Yes', 'autodail', '04-09-19 02:08 pm'),
(5, '1', '2', 'notconnected', 'rnr', 'No Conversation', 'Yes', 'autodail', '04-09-19 04:13 pm'),
(14, '9', '2', 'notconnected', 'switchoff', 'No Conversation', 'No', 'autodail', '05-09-19 01:26 pm'),
(18, '4', '2', 'notconnected', 'switchoff', 'No Conversation', 'Yes', 'autodail', '09-09-19 04:47 pm'),
(23, '8', '2', 'notconnected', 'busy', 'No Conversation', 'Yes', 'autodail', '09-09-19 04:51 pm'),
(25, '10', '2', 'notconnected', 'rnr', 'No Conversation', 'Yes', 'autodail', '09-09-19 04:52 pm');

--
```

Comment: How is this related to PHP? Why did you tag it with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I entered your data and query into SQL Fiddle and all comes back fine for me:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/418fe9/2

Were you expecting something different?

```
customerId  Fresh_Call  Call_Status
1   Yes notconnected
4   Yes notconnected
8   Yes notconnected
10  Yes notconnected
```

Comment: There will be multiple records in table based on customerId, i want to check last record of customerId if Call_Status = "notconnected " AND Fresh_Call="Yes"  fecth result  else last record Call_Status = "notconnected " AND Fresh_Call="No"